# jQuery + Safari 4 Beta

Tags: jquery, safari

I have a (ASP.NET MVC) site that uses jQuery 1.3.2 and my jQuery functions refuse to invoke on Safari 4.0 beta [mac].

I *CAN* get them to invoke if I change the user-agent to Safari 3.2.1 Mac.  This seems strange to me as I can't find any info about jQuery having issues with the beta and I don't know why the user-agent would change that.

Anyone know how I can get jQuery to work on Safari 4 without the user having to change the user-agent??

**Update**: I opened up the page again this morning and all worked fine, with the proper UA.  I think that maybe the JS engine went whacky and after a safari restart all was restored.

Thank you all for your comments.

Comment: Not a public example sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was testing with JQuery 1.3.2 on Safari 4.0 beta (mac) just a minute ago before I decided to check stackoverflow :)

So I don't think it's a general problem, you'll have to provide some more info before anyone can help you...

Answer (score 0):

Which jQuery functions? But I don't think that or Safari are the problem. Are you sure the ASP don't withhold some (script-)content unless they know about the user-agent?

Comment: Yes I am sure... it is a brail view engine so I render all script output (plus i have checked the page source)